# How to create an accordion table with Bootstrap and Angular ngFor and fixed indentation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

My goal is to copy [this behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/kxtk6w4y/) and to include it in a ngFor loop.

I've tried several codes, each one having a different issue:

Try 1:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index" class="clickable-row" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#gameDetails' + i">
            <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.date}}
                <div [attr.id]="'gameDetails' + i" class="collapse">
                    <p>Insert a large component in this place</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.label}}</td>
            <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.score}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try 1 result, collapsed:

[image: Try 1 result, collapsed]

Try 1 result, deployed:

[image: Try 1 result, deployed]

In the try 1 the problem is that the collapsed component fits in the left cell, impacting the cells at his right.

Try 2:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <div *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
            <tr class="clickable-row" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#game2Details' + i">
                <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.date}}</td>
                <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.label}}</td>
                <td class="text-nowrap">{{game.score}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr [attr.id]="'game2Details' + i" class="collapse">
                <td colspan="3">Insert a large component in this place</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try 2 result, collapsed:

[image: Try 2 result, collapsed]

Try 2 result, deployed:

[image: Try 2 result, deployed]

In the try 2 we lose the table indentation when details are collapsed.

Try 3:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#game4Details' + i">
                        <td>{{game.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.label}}</td>
                        <td>{{game.score}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="hiddentablerow">
                            <div [attr.id]="'game4Details' + i" class="accordian-body collapse">Insert a large component in this place
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try 3 result, collapsed:

[image]

Try 3 result, deployed:

[image]

In the try 3 the indentation differs between the different inner tables.

Is there a way to keep the indentation before and after the deploy of the collapsed row?
Or maybe another way using something else than a table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries it seems that the table component doesn't fit well into a Bootstrap grid container.
I could get good results using only div tags with Bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for your post, it helped steered me in the right direction with my project. I figured I would post what I was doing, even though it's not exactly the same. It may help someone else who is trying the same thing. I stopped using ng-bootstrap's `Collapse` in order to get this to work. Sorry if my terminology is wrong, I'm new to Angular.

What I was working on was a large table with data pulled from a JSON file. At the end of the table row is a button that, when clicked, shows another row with more data.

I was able to get this working without distorting the original row. Here is my result, along with the CSS I used. I hardcoded some stuff for testing, just FYI.

**HTML:**

ID of table: `subs-table`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sub of subs; index as i">
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{sub.Name}}</th>
        <td><img src="../../assets/{{sub.Image}}"></td>
        <td>{{sub.Description}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapse-' + i" [attr.aria-expanded]="false" [attr.aria-controls] = "'collapse-' + i"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="collapse-row">
            <div [attr.id]="'collapse-' + i" class="container collapse out">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">Min Splash Damage: 25</div> 
                    <div class="col">Splash Damage: 35</div>
                    <div class="col">Direct Hit Damage: 60</div>
                    <div class="col">Ink Consumption: 40%</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Sets button text when clicked. Should combine these later with wildcards */
#subs-table .btn-primary:before {
    content:'Click for details';
}
#subs-table .btn-primary[aria-expanded="true"]:before {
    content:'Close Details';
}
/* Styling of the collapsible row */
#subs-table td.collapse-row {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I hope this helps any passerby!

Answer (score -3):

Pretty simple,

Use Angular bootstrap package's accordion as mentioned below:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
      aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
      sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
      craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings
      occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus
      labore sustainable VHS.
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>

</ngb-accordion>
```

For details click [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples)

[GIF of above example](https://gyazo.com/fb55b5c1cfa94f67378b2155d8bd2c18)

Comment: I will try that. But I have doubts because this example doesn't involve a table, which is what the issue is about.

Comment: @coli can you please mention that why the use of table significant for your problem.

Comment: I confirm that what you propose doesn't help. The title of the question mentions 'table' and 'indentation', I think it is sufficient.

Comment: No it isn't , it also states accordion, angular and bootstrap

Comment: I don't get you. What exactly do you think is missing in the question ?